# using gstreamer srtp for audio streaming

Tags: gstreamer

tried the below but cant hear audio

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=6000 ! "application/x-srtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L16, channels=(int)2, payload=(int)96, srtp-key=(buffer)012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789, srtp-cipher=(string)aes-128-icm, srtp-auth=(string)hmac-sha1-80, srtcp-cipher=(string)aes-128-icm, srtcp-auth=(string)hmac-sha1-80, roc=(uint)0" ! srtpdec ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink

gst-launch-1.0 -v  alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,channels=2,depth=16,width=16,rate=44100 ! rtpL16pay ! srtpenc key="012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" ! udpsink host=3.204.26.22 port=6000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because  you havent set ssrc, try the following pipelines

Sender pipeline as:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v  alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,channels=2,depth=16,width=16,rate=44100 ! rtpL16pay ! 'application/x-rtp, ssrc=(uint)3412089386'  ! srtpenc key="012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" ! udpsink host=3.204.26.22 port=6000
```

Receiver pipeline as:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=6000 ! "application/x-srtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L16, channels=(int)2, payload=(int)96,ssrc=(uint)3412089386, srtp-key=(buffer)012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789, srtp-cipher=(string)aes-128-icm, srtp-auth=(string)hmac-sha1-80, srtcp-cipher=(string)aes-128-icm, srtcp-auth=(string)hmac-sha1-80, roc=(uint)0" ! srtpdec ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink
```